# Split simple programming language instructions to different tokens

Tags: java, parsing, split

I'm stacking on the problem how to parse whole text that comes to me from an input. Input consists of some simple instruction like

1. `x=z+4; z=4; if x<z then(x=4;z=0) else(z=x);`

or with a while loop

2. `x=z+4; z=4; while x<z do(x=4; z=5 +x)`

my actual split works on `;` character but there is the problem because it's returning me 4 string representations for the 1st code piece mentioned above out of which 1st and 2nd representations are good (Getting `x=z+4` and `z=4`) but in `if else` the 3rd representation I am getting starts with `if` and end before `;` ..and the 4th representation is total bullshit.

So I need to split things for 3rd instruction where I need output as a whole starts with `if` and end by closing bracket `)` after `else` ..

The similar problem is visible in the second code piece with `while` instruction

Any ideas?

Comment: all divided parts will in future be generated to another language but for the first time I need to divide the input by instruction type

Comment: I doubt you can parse using a simple split on a `;`.  You probably need a parsing library/class like ANTLR (though that might be overkill).